# Calculate the following sequence $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\left ( -\dfrac{1}{4\alpha } \right )^{n}\dfrac{ (2n)!}{n!},\; \alpha >0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Calculate the following sequence $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\left ( -\dfrac{1}{4\alpha } \right )^{n}\dfrac{ (2n)!}{n!},\; \alpha >0$$

Comment: The sequence diverges for every $\alpha$, because the individual terms go to infinity.  Hint: show that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\geq n!$; there's an 'aha!' that should make this obvious.

Comment: As a series, this one diverges badly. If I'm not mistaken, this is the asymptotic expansion of $\sqrt{\pi\alpha}e^{\alpha} \text{erfc}(\sqrt{\alpha})$ where $\text{erfc}(x)$ is the complemenary error function $$\text{erfc}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} dt$$ Look at the wiki page of [Error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) for more details.

Comment: @achillehui: Nice catch! Adjusting [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/177992) yields $$\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t \sim\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(2k)!}{4^kk!x^{2k+1}}$$ which transforms into your expansion with $x=\sqrt\alpha$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}=(2n)(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)\ge n^n$, therefore,
$$
\left|\,\left(-\frac1{4\alpha}\right)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\,\right|
\ge\left|\,\frac{n}{4\alpha}\,\right|^n\tag1
$$
Thus, the terms of the series do not go to $0$, so the series diverges.

---

However, if as suggested by Lucian, this is supposed to be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\left(-\frac1{4\alpha}\right)^{\large n}\tag2
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{2n}{n}
&=2^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}\tag{3a}\\
&=4^n\frac{\left(n-\frac12\right)!}{n!\left(-\frac12\right)!}\tag{3b}\\
&=4^n\binom{n-\frac12}{n}\tag{3c}\\[3pt]
&=(-4)^n\binom{-\frac12}{n}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: $(2n)!=(2n-1)!!\,2^nn!$
$\text{(3b)}$: $(2n-1)!!=2^n\frac{\left(n-\frac12\right)!}{\left(-\frac12\right)!}$
$\text{(3c)}$: write ratio as a binomial coefficient$\\[9pt]$
$\text{(3d)}$: [negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\left(-\frac1{4\alpha}\right)^{\large n}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac12}{n}\frac1{\alpha^n}\tag{4a}\\[3pt]
&=\left(1+\frac1\alpha\right)^{-1/2}\tag{4b}\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}}\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). And also, it's $(n!)^2$.

Comment: How is this a binomial series?  The 'top' of the binomial coefficient is variable, not constant, even with the correction you suggest...

Comment: It's the binomial series of $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ , for $x=-\dfrac1{4a}$ . The [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) stems from $-1/2\choose n$

Comment: Oh, of course!  I'm sorry, it's late and apparently my brain is leaking.

Comment: If It's $(n!)^2$, then $S_N=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left ( -\dfrac{1}{4\alpha } \right )^{n}\dfrac{ (2n)!}{(n!)^2}=(1-\frac{1}{4\alpha})^N$.



Because $1-\frac{1}{4\alpha}<1\to S=\lim_{N\to \infty} S_N=0$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty }\left ( -\dfrac{1}{4\alpha } \right )^{n}\dfrac{ (2n)!}{(n!)^2}=0$$

Very easy!

Comment: Very easy, and also very wrong, I'm afraid. ${N\choose n}\neq{2n\choose n}$