# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-x^2} dx$?

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$ because if I let $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$, then

\begin{align*}
I^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 -y^2} dx dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r} r dr d\theta\\
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^\infty e^{-r^2} r dr\\
&= \pi 
\end{align*}
where the second equal sign follows from polar transformation. However, what if I'm interested in evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-x^2} dx$? I'm having trouble translating $\int_{-\infty}^a$ into the correct bounds on $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: You can't do it without the Error Function.

Comment: The technique you identify only works in the context you identify and does not cleanly evaluate the expression for arbitrary values of $a$ (there are exceptions, e.g. the value at $a=0$ can be deduced from your calculation). For arbitrary $a$ I do not know of a method that would result in an evaluation that is any simpler than simply just the integral expression itself.

Comment: If you are actually interested in *evaluating* the integral, rather than finding a *closed form* for the integral, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177992) gives three methods, depending on the value of the argument and precision desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is equal to
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^a e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(a\right)+1\right)}{2},$$
where the error function is defined as
$$\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{x}e^{-\tau^2}\,\mathrm{d}\tau.$$

Comment: ...yep... as is widely, widely known.

Comment: This is because $$\displaystyle\int_{\infty}^{a}e^{-x^{2}}\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-x^{2}}\ dx + \int_{0}^{a}e^{-x^{2}}\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\ dx + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erf}(a) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erf}(a) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}(\text{erf}(a)+1)}{2}$$.

Comment: Ok, so now how do I calculate the values of the error function?

Comment: You use a computer.  It is a function... just like $\sin$, $\tan$, $\ln$, ...